# Meteor/MongoDB: How can I add a $gt to an object `selectorObject["key"] = { $gt: value };`?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I’m construction a selectorObject for my `UPSERT` query. Normally I add all selectObjects with `selectorObject[“key”] = value;` but how do I do it when the condition to add is key = { $gt : value }?

I've tried the following:

1) `selectorObject[“key”] = { $gt: value };`

2) `selectorObject["key"] = {"$gt": value };`

3) `selectorObject["key"].$gt = value;`

The first two result in this error message: `MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$gt' in 'key.$gt' is not valid for storage.`

The third statement results in `Exception in callback of async function: TypeError: Cannot set property '$gt' of undefined`

It must be possible somehow. I do need to use the selectObject and `modifierObject` form as some of the `selectorObject` is dependant on an if clause.

***EDIT:*** the solution no. 1 works if it's an `UPDATE` (means there is a document with those selections existing when executing the `UPSERT` but it fails when there is no document and basically an `INSERT` is executed. Error message on the later part is: `MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$gt' in 'key.$gt' is not valid for storage.`

The .dot notation is just another way of writing solution no. 1 and thus fails as well.

FYI - I'm using MongoDB v3.2 and Meteor 1.1.0.3

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your attempt no. 1 should work if you have a field called `key`. Can you show what to value of selectorObj is before you use it in the update? Something like console.log(JSON.stringify(selectorObject));

Comment: can you show us your entire UPSERT query?

Comment: @jos-harink , this is the value of the selectorObject: `{"key1":"abc","key2":{"$gt":123}}`. Like I wrote in my edited question it works when there is already an existing document that matches (I have two cases that run through without problems and `UPSERT` works but it fails when there is no document matching the selection and basically the `INSERT` part of the `UPSERT` kicks in.

Comment: @Jamgold `myCollection.upsert( selectorObject, { $set: modifierObject }, { multi:true } );`